# I have a nightly batch that fetches newsfeed info from social networks...it takes too long on PHP. Is there a better way?

Tags: php, batch-file, social-networking

Basically, as the title says...I have a site that fetches newsfeed information for each account from facebook, Linkedin and twitter. With many accounts, the time it takes to run the nightly batch is verrrryyy looong. Should I not do this in PHP? Is there a better way to run the batch?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem here most likely resides with [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) - this will allow you to make many HTTP requests at once a will likely drastically reduce the amount of time it is taking you to transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend node.js for this, just make the calls, assign the callbacks to handle the response,and when it's done, it's done, you don't have to wait for the replies to move to the next action.

If you want to stick with php, as DaveRandom mentioned, `curl_multi_exec()` is the way to go.